# Transition not working on backdrop opacity to 0 when class is removed

Tags: css

I have a backdrop on my site that opens whenever it needs to. Modals, mobile nav etc.

I'd like to get the opacity of the backdrop to fade, however I can't get it to transition properly when the `--open` class is removed from the backdrop.

I've gone through a few iterations so any ideas on how to make it work AND be better css is appreciated.

Here's a demo demonstrating the ease effect occuring when `--open` is applied to the backdrop, but will not work when it is removed.

https://jsfiddle.net/p2yz0rvr/

For futures sake here's the code:

```
.backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -9999999999;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;

    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;

}

.backdrop--open {
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #000;

    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a background set on the initial `.backdrop` state, the background is set on the element `.backdrop--open`.

Since you are only transitioning the `opacity` property, the transition doesn't occur when you remove the `.backdrop--open` class. Therefore you would need to move background to the initial `.backdrop` state in order for the transition to take place when removing the class.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gpg4sktv/)

```
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.backdrop--open {
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

---

As an alternative, you could also keep your initial code and just transition the `background` property in addition to the `opacity` property (without having to change where the background is set).

Keep in mind that the `z-index` property can be transitioned, so depending on what you're trying to achieve you may only want to target those two properties rather than using `all`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/28bkk85w/)

```
.backdrop {
  /* ... */
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.backdrop--open {
  /* ... */
  background: #000;
  transition: background 0.4s ease-out, opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks. It also worked in my original example if I changed the transition from "opacity" to "all" which I assume selects background instead. I'll tag your answer correct when the 5 minute limit is up :D